# Disable all optimizations on a LLVM basic block

Tags: optimization, compilation, clang, llvm, llvm-c++-api

> Disable all optimizations on a LLVM basic block

Is there any way to disable ALL optimizations and/or modifications on a LLVM basic block, so that the code generated for the basic block, at the assembly/binary level, will correspond to exactly the instructions within the basic block in the original order?

I know of the `optnone` function attribute, which disables optimizations at the function level. However, here I would like to optimize all basic block except a few.

How would I achieve my goal of disable optimization for a basic block?

Comment: I doubt there is even such a thing like `one-to-one correspondence between IR instructions and assembly instructions`.

Comment: What about the optimizations that go across Basic Blocks? Should they all be disabled?

Comment: Don't have to be. I just need that basic blocks stays intact as entities, I.e. their contents are not modified.

Comment: Perhaps making those basic blocks you want to be intact as standalone functions?

Comment: That is not an option - would be too much work. Or could I "inline" those functions without leaving trace of the function itself?